# Google compute engine removes packages and changes directory

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I've been using it without particular issue like this for a week or so. If I log out of a certain directory, it will log back in to that same place.

Then at some point it started removing some packages /files that were installed.

1. When I first saw this happen, I thought it could be my own mistake as I had too many instances.
2. Currently I double checked that it just directed me to a directory I've not seen before, but the packages I installed are gone.

I find it very hard to see why this is happening or search for relevant issues.

Does anyone have similar encounters and know how to address these?????... It is seriously disconcerting that GCP may not be very reliable, when it is the only source that provides all the necessary env.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify on your settings?

Did you [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux#create_a_virtual_machine_instance) standard instances?

Or perhaps you are using [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances)? [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances)

I’ve been using my GCE instances for months and I have not seen this behavior.

Please clarify:

- How you created your instances (if you are following a guide share
  the link)
- How you are connecting to it.
- How are you installing the packages.
- The OS you are using

I would like to replicate this issue on my end

Comment: it goes to some other directory, and I lose sudo. I just gave myself the authority and directed using the exact path. It happens every time by now.

Comment: I understand your symptoms but it could help to find the root cause if you share the reproduction steps because at this point it will be best educated guesses on what the OS is doing.